# How to refetch a query from a different component without a mutation?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, apollostack

Say I have some component with a query that fetches something:

```
   <Query query={GET_THING}>
            {({ loading, error, data, refetch }) => {
                if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
                if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;

                // currently am just storing refetch in global var
                globalRefetches.thing = refetch;
                // external component can call globalRefetches.thing()

                return <Text>{data.getThing}</Text>;
            }}
   />
```

Then I navigate to a Filters screen where I can set some filters to adjust the result.

- This screen is not a child of the previous component, so I can't simply pass the refetch via props.
- Pressing "Save Filters" is not a mutation (it doesn't hit the server and alter the database, but simply changes the local variables that are passed to the previous query), so I don't have refetchQueries.

Is there a clean way for me to refetch the query on the previous screen? Currently, I am just storing them in a global var, but I would imagine there is some way to pull the query out of the store and refetch it with new variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches to fix this, but I think Apollo's intended solution is to update the cache with the new filter/sort criteria using the ApolloConsumer component. The ApolloConsumer component gives you direct access to your cache. You can read and write directly to it. You can also build your own resolvers, which is a great way to modularize your cache operations, such as filter and sort. Unfortunately, there is a bit of a learning curve when interacting with the cache and the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html) could be a bit better. For the most part, you would be altering the cache using the readQuery, writeQuery, readFragment, and WriteFragment functions among a few others.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't know they had this feature! I think this is it. Previously I stated, "Pressing "Save Filters" is not a mutation (it doesn't hit the server and alter the database, but simply changes the local variables that are passed to the previous query)" - so although it is not a remote mutation, it can still be a local cache mutation if I take advantage of this new feature. Local cache mutaton => update the query result. It doesn't seem like this cache persists though, right? So the only extra thing I would have to do is load AsyncStorage => local cache on app start up, and good to go. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to implement this in combination with `apollo-cache-persist` and it does exactly what I need pretty simply. I have a `<Query query={GET_FILTER}>...<Query query={GET_THING}>...</Query></Query>` where `UPDATE_FILTER_MUTATION` (`cache.writeData(...)`) will then magically re-render `GET_FILTER -> GET_THING` components with the new filters.

Comment: page not found !

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of global state manager - when sth is changed in store (filter options) all connected components (observing this) are updated. You can use redux, mobx ... there is a lot of simple, small, light, easy solution to choose from - or build sth own with context api.

`Apollo client` has support for `local state management` - not easiest one but similiar to normal graphql usage.